# How to make a ListBox in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I want to make a listbox, similar to the Combobox, but with out a drop down, just show the whole list with a scrollbar?  Looking also to be able to click on and hightlight a row to delete that item if need be.

```
QComboBox *lv = new QComboBox(this);
lv->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,100), QSize(100, 50)));
lv->addItem("hello1");
lv->addItem("hello2");
lv->addItem("hello3");
lv->addItem("hello4");
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [QListWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) and [QListWidgetItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html) for this.